# Prevent publishing pages to live site until approval workflow finishes

Tags: 2013-sp1, workflow

I want to make following workflow.

1. An editor create components and pages, and publishes pages to staging site.
2. The editor confirms the pages on staging site, and requests an approval to a manager.
3. The maganer confirms the pages on staging site, and approves them.
4. The pages are published to live site automatically.

And it's necessary that anyone cannot publish pages to live site by mistake, until "3" is finished.
But just after pages are created, anyone who has permission can publish pages to live site.

Is there any good idea to achieve this workflow

Regards,

Comment: You can set a minimum approval status on the "Live" Publication Target, and then Tridion won't publish anything that didn't reach that status yet.

Comment: What Nuno said, with the proviso that this only applies to items that are still in workflow. So if your page might contain components that are out of workflow, you'll have extra work to do.

Comment: When page or component is newly created, and they get into workflow automatically by associated workflow process,they cannot be published to any target. And if there is no associated process, they can be published to live site before workflow starts,because their approval status is "Undefined".Those are problems.

Answer (score 3):

You may follow below approach:

- Create a Two Step Workflow using SDL Tridion-Visio Connector and set up appropriate approval group at each step - You can refer this documentation for more details - [Workflow](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DWorkflow&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1424078787386&currentQuery=Workflow&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-2F17886A-08C8-472C-B31E-C5ED53D973F7&query=&scope=&filename=GUID-2F17886A-08C8-472C-B31E-C5ED53D973F7.xml&docid=GUID-2F17886A-08C8-472C-B31E-C5ED53D973F7&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=&toc=false)
- Set this workflow for each schema of components and structure group containing pages on which you want to set up the workflow
- Write an event system and capture the Workflow Activity Finish Event - Write the code to publish the item to staging once the First Workflow Activity is finished and publish it to live once the Second workflow step is approved - You can refer this documentation for more details - [Event System](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DEvent%2520System&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1424078870738&currentQuery=Event%2520System&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-AB4FBF5F-7C3B-4804-9E7F-FBBF5514A596&query=&scope=&filename=GUID-AB4FBF5F-7C3B-4804-9E7F-FBBF5514A596.xml&docid=GUID-AB4FBF5F-7C3B-4804-9E7F-FBBF5514A596&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=&toc=false)

The rest SDL Tridion will take care off itself - It won't allow to publish unless you go through this workflow

Comment: I would use automated activities instead of event handlers to do the publishing.

Comment: Yes Rick, another option :)